# Call Java method from JavaScript and return value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

There are few SO questions and other articles about calling Java class method from Javascript but all of them deals with java method with return type `void`.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
There are 2 strings to be displayed in WebView - say *Yes* and *No*. But they needs to be localized and hence I want to get the string value from Java method rather than using multiple JS for each locale.

Here's the code sample:
*Java class*

```
onCreate(){
//Some code
contentWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new CalculatorJavaScriptCallInterface(), "calculatorjavascriptcallinterface");
//Some code
}

String localizedString = "";
private class CalculatorJavaScriptCallInterface {
    CalculatorJavaScriptCallInterface() {
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getLocalizedString(final int stringId) {
        localizedString = getResources().getString(stringId);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "localizedString :: " + localizedString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return localizedString;
    }
}
```

---

*Javascript file*

```
  function Checkboxpicker(element, options) {
    //Some code
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.checkboxpicker.defaults, options, this.$element.data());
}
  $.fn.checkboxpicker.defaults = {
    //EXISTING STRINGS
    //offLabel: 'No',
    //onLabel: 'Yes',
    offLabel: window.calculatorjavascriptcallinterface.getLocalizedString("Consult.JSSupport.checkbox.selected"),
    onLabel: window.calculatorjavascriptcallinterface.getLocalizedString("Consult.JSSupport.checkbox.notSelected"),
  };
```

**I am getting blank string as output when I run above code.**

Here are some notes:

1. This Javascript is being used appropriately as it works if I use
   hard-coded strings
2. Respective stings have been defined in
   `string.xml`
3. I tried using `calculatorjavascriptcallinterface` in
   Camel case and lower case both
4. I tried with and without `window.`
   to call Java method
5. Tried returning hard-coded value from Java
   method - **IT IS WORKING THIS WAY**

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**
I'm getting following error even though the string is present in *strings.xml*:

```
No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: you may need to make asynchronous calls

Comment: have you `setJavaScriptEnabled` ? Is your  `getLocalizedString` getting called?

Comment: @sagar - Yes. How to verify that? Please check important update in Question.

Comment: @brk - Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GAMA is your Toast message showing correct String?

Comment: @Sagar - Toast is not showing up

Comment: @GAMA do you see any error in Logs? Can you just try to print the `localizedString` in logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171746/discussion-between-gama-and-sagar).

Comment: @GAMA are you in chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like issue with getting the String with proper Id. change your `getLocalizedString` as follows:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String getLocalizedString(final String stringId) {
    localizedString = getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(stringId,"string",getContext().getPackageNam‌​e()));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "localizedString :: " + localizedString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return localizedString;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sagar - it worked like a charm. Minor change -  need to use `getContext().getPackageName()` instead of `getPackageName()`

Comment: @GAMA great! Thanks for updating. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

1.)

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(this), "Android");
    mWebView.loadUrl("url or html file path");
```

2.)

```
public class WebViewInterface {

    Context mContext;

    WebViewInterface(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void performAction(String pro_cat_id) {
          //write your code here to perform any action.
    }
```

3.)

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/MyJS.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="mClick('1');">Yes</button>
        <button onClick="mClick('0');">No</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

4.) javascript: MyJS.js

```
function mClick(mValue)
{
    Android.performAction(mId);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Akash - I am almost doing the same thing as mentioned in question but no success.